# Can huge current of stepping motor driven with dual or triple A4988 Stepper driver

Tags: cnc

That I know. The A4988 is a cheap driver capable of driving a small stepper motor. But I had time to think. Is it possible if nema 23 has a high current ampere. For example 4 amperes, Controlled by two or 3 A4899 drivers . Thanks

I will try it. But maybe there are more understanding and eloquent